# GET http://localhost/scl-mgt-update/fetch?type=teacher 500 (Internal Server Error) from AJAX laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Ajax is not working properly. can someone please help me?

in blade

```
<div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-12 form-group" id="div-type">
    <label>Expense Type</label>
    <select class="select2" name="type" id="selectType">
        <option></option>
        <option value="Teacher's Salary" {{ old('type')=="Teacher's Salary" ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            Teacher's Salary
        </option>
        <option value="Staff's Salary" {{ old('type')=="Staff's Salary" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Staff's
            Salary
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="div-name" class="hidden"></div>
```

jquery Ajax Code

```
$('#selectType').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Teacher's Salary") {
        $('#content').hide();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('fetch-data') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {type: 'teacher'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#div-type').attr('class', 'col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-12 form-group');
                $('#div-name').attr('class', 'col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-12 form-group');

                $('#div-name').html(data);

                $('#teacher_name').select2();
            },
        });
    } else if ($(this).val() == "Staff's Salary") {
        $('#content').hide();
    } else {
        $('#content').show();
    }
});
```

IN web.php

```
Route::get('/fetch', 'ExpenseController@ajaxFetch')->name('fetch-data')
```

In controller

```
public function ajaxFetch(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $type = $request->get('type');
        if ($type == 'teacher') {
            $names = Teacher::all();
            $data = '
            <label>Select Teacher</label>
            <select id="teacher_name" class="select2">
            ';
            foreach ($names as $item) {
                $data+='<option value="'+$item->id+'">'+$item->name+'</option>';
            }
            $data+='</select>';
        }
        return json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Now it is not working. In console **GET http://localhost/scl-mgt-update/fetch?type=teacher 500 (Internal Server Error) from AJAX laravel** this error is showing. what can I do now to run ajax? same code are working on search. when I make data in controller it sends me an error. otherwise ajax alert was worked.

Comment: Brother phir se ? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do it in this way, `+` is used in jquery `.` is used in php**

```
public function ajaxFetch(Request $request)
{
if ($request->ajax()) {
    $type = $request->get('type');
    if ($type == 'teacher') {
        $names = Teacher::all();
        $data = '
        <label>Select Teacher</label>
        <select id="teacher_name" class="select2">
        ';
        foreach ($names as $item) {
            $data .= '<option value="'.$item->id.'">'.$item->name.'</option>';
        }
        $data .='</select>';
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}
}
```